# Validate by specific rule in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have 4 rules for specific field. But I want to validate for one specific rule. How to do in cakephp2.0

Is there any solution for that

Comment: Where is your code???

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a model & declared set of rules for a field like

```
//in your model

    public $validate = array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'rule-1' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                'message' => 'Only alphabets and numbers allowed',
            ),
            'rule-2' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 8),
                'message' => 'Minimum length of 8 characters'
            )
        ),
    );
```

Here you see i have define two rules for field `first_name`. Now I try to remove `loginRule-2` like

```
// in your controller 

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();

           // // Completely remove all rules for a field
            $this->User->validator()->remove('first_name');
            $this->User->validator()->add('first_name', 'required',
            array(
               'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ));
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
            }
        }
    }
```

You can look [CakePHP Cookbook 2.x documentation for Removing rules from the set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#removing-rules-from-the-set)

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to check only one rule among 4. Now I have 4 rule. so I have to put 3 validator remove. In future there is a chance to add another rule. so that time I have to add validator remove for new rule which I don't want.

Comment: @Arockiam, You need to remove all rules of your field & then need to new validation rule as your requirement. I have also  update my answer.